# Rust Streaming Pipeline

Tags: rust, rust-async-std

I'm finding Rust streaming documentation to be convoluted and examples non-existent.

Trying to create a code example will likely be more confusing than outlining a problem.

Given a read stream that is being passed to a consuming function, I'd like to introduce a middle-step to the stream pipeline that counts bytes, but could do anything, with minimal overhead.

`read stream --> middle read stream function --> write stream`

Example Pipeline:

First get file stream, then execute transformation on stream, finally stream to disk (new file).

Comment: Are you talking about [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) trait from the `futures` crate? Are you aware of the methods on the [`StreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html) trait?

Comment: Looking at `StreamExt`, it _appears_ then may help but I cannot find a concrete example demonstrating `file in stream -> transformation -> file out stream`. The `futures` crate would be ideal. Using streams to avoid loading everything into memory required.

Comment: @webish It sounds more like you mean file I/O using e.g. the `Read`/`Write` or `AsyncRead`/`AsyncWrite` traits?

Comment: Without the bounty, this question would probably have been closed a while ago. It does not contain enough information. What do you mean with `streaming documentation`? What do you mean with `stream`? Are you talking about `Read`/`Write`? If yes, what exactly is unclear to you? What's the implementation you tried, and why does it not work? What are your exact questions? Maybe read through your own question and realize that it doesn't actually contain a question.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented `Read` adaptor that should be zero cost abstraction for your purpose of introducing “middle step”.
It's something like `Iterator::map` but for `Read` instances.
*(I assume `Read` instances are what you call streams. You seem to be using terminology from Java/C++. If you meant something else, please clarify.)*.

```
use std::io::{Read, Write};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // It's your “read stream”. Could be any.
    let reader = std::fs::OpenOptions::new().read(true).open("in_file.txt")?;
    // It's your adaptor to perform “middle step”.
    let mut trans_reader = TransReader {
        orginal: reader,
        transform: |bytes: &mut [u8]| {
            // Could be any transformation.
            bytes.make_ascii_uppercase();
        },
    };
    // It's your “write stream”. Could be any.
    let mut writer = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .write(true)
        .open("out_file.txt")?;

    // You can read bytes in anyway you want and then write. Eg. read all then write all.
    let mut buf = vec![];
    trans_reader.read_to_end(&mut buf)?;
    writer.write_all(&buf)?;

    Ok(())
}

// It's my implementation of adaptor you need.
pub struct TransReader<R: Read, F: FnMut(&mut [u8])> {
    pub orginal: R,
    pub transform: F,
}
impl<Org: Read, F: FnMut(&mut [u8])> Read for TransReader<Org, F> {
    // This is the only method that needs to be implemented.
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        let res = self.orginal.read(buf);
        if let Ok(written_count) = res {
            (self.transform)(&mut buf[..written_count]);
        }
        res
    }
    // I'm not 100% if manual impl. of other methods would also make for performance.
}
```